# Retrieval of session factory object from .xml

Tags: spring, hibernate

Is there a way to get `sessionFactory` object from spring-hibernate combined XML file without using it (SessionFac..) as a instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure XML and define a `SessionFactory` bean, you can inject it into another XML defined bean as follows:

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.company.service.MyService">
  <!-- reference the sessionFactory bean by value -->
  <property name="sessionFactory" value-ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

If you have defined the `SessionFactory` bean in XML and then want to inject it using annotations, you simply need to add an `@Autowired` annotation to the field, setter, or the constructor where you are passing a `SessionFactory` variable.